# Manipulating a single wide char

Tags: c, string, windows, unicode, utf-16

quick question, porting my 15k line framework to UTF16 :)

do i manipulate single wchar_t's like this?

```
wchar_t Help[128];
Help[0] = '?'
Help[1] = '/0'
```

or

```
wchar_t Help[128];
Help[0] = L'?'
Help[1] = L'/0'
```

Comment: Porting *to* UTF-16? This better be on Windows.

Comment: it's on windows :)

Comment: The latter is preferred.  but in your example, using characters within the ascii range (0-127), it does not matter.

Comment: It should be `L'\0'`, not `/0`

Comment: yeye i kno, was just making some basic psuedo code example thing

Comment: Is that `'?'` a question mark, or a non-ASCII character I can't see?

Comment: its a question mark

Comment: You are wasting your life, just pick the sane way to do this: wchar_t Help[128] = L"?";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not assign a `char` directly to a `wchar_t` without a type-cast, otherwise the compile is likely to issue a warning about data loss.

If you don't prefix a character literal, it will have type `char`, so `Help[0] = '?'` will not compile.

If you prefix a character literal with `L`, it will have type `wchar_t` instead, so `Help[0] = L'?'` will compile.

Note that `wchar_t` is not 16bit on all platforms. It is on Windows, but on many other platforms, it is 32bit instead, so would be used for UTF-32 and not UTF-16. If you want to use UTF-16 on all platforms, you should use `char16_t` and the `u` literal prefix, which were introduced in C11:

```
char16_t Help[128];
Help[0] = u'?';
Help[1] = u'\0';
```

Comment: Technically `char` and `wchar_t` are not incompatible types, they are integral types and the compiler should generate automatic conversions between them. At most you should get a warning that can be turned off.

Comment: `Help[0] = '?'` is correct in Standard C. There is implicit conversion from `char` to `wchar_t`.